# emberJs giving different routes to links

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I got a page that includes 15 pictures and I must redirect user to the details page if one of them is clicked. so, I have 15 different routes like 1,2,3,...15. But as I know, I cant give dynamic variable to #link-to helper. So how am I gonna make every picture go to its own route? this is how my index page `.hbs` looks like :

```
{{#each model as |rentalUnit|}}
  {{rental-listing rental=rentalUnit}}
{{/each}}
{{outlet}}
```

This is how I print every picture. And this is how am I trying to go to routes :

```
  {{#link-to "???"}}<img src={{rental.image}} width="200">{{/link-to}}
```

so, there is ??? because I dont know what to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first why not use a dynamic segment in your route? Like this:

```
this.route('image', {path: '/images/:id'});
```

But what you want can be done by just passing a variable, not a string to the link to helper as first argument:

```
{{#link-to target}}
```

Where {{target}} would print your route name. So `target` is a variable here, not a string.

Checkout [this twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/54e0dbd62475270222f116b14a05cb50?openFiles=templates.2.hbs%2C&route=%2F2).

Comment: Hello, thanks. I tried exactly what it does on the twiddle but as a result my index page become blank. so, can you tell me more about how to use 'this.route('image', {path: '/images/:id'});' ?? Will I keep all my route 1,2,3,4...5 codes and also add it or delete the others? should I create "image" route? also what should I write after #link-to if I use this way? sorry for a lot of questions, this problem is bothering me for two days now.

Comment: @HandeBc have you read the [guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/#toc_dynamic-models)? With a dynamic segment you have one route with its template and just use different data. Link to can be invoked as [in the api documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#toc_supplying-a-model). Also if the other thing is not working please provide non working code or better a twiddle or we can't help you.

Comment: Yes I read the documentation but it's kind of complicated. But I'm struggling with them though. Ok then, this is the twiddle of my tiny project https://ember-twiddle.com/b35b0befae27976ada4c8f66ea2e3149?openFiles=router.js%2C  right now, every picture goes to /1 path when clicked.

Comment: In your twiddle you still use `{{link-to "images"}}` where `images` is a string, not `{{link-to images}}` where images is a variable containing a string. Also you `id`'s are numbers, not strings, so I convert them to string with `{{concat}}`. Checkout [this](https://ember-twiddle.com/7c78cd10a099e29aa19f43c10bf66e6b?openFiles=templates.index.hbs%2C) fiddle.

Comment: There is something else I wanna ask, is there a way to go back exactly where I was on the browser when I click the "back" link in order to not to scroll down everytime when I go back to the home page? I have a "back" link working in every route but it always sends me to the top of the home page. @Lux

Comment: @HandleBc this should work and is a browser feature. Not on application level usually. However you can save the scroll position and restore it yourself. However this is a different question that should be not part of this question. Please ask a new question if you have further unrelated questions.